# List indexing in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Let `S` be a vector with unique elements, and `s` a subset of it, also with unique elements; e.g., `S={1,2,3,4,5,6}` and `s={1,3,4,6}`. Now given another vector `c={7,8,9,7}`, how can I create a vector `C=[7,0,8,9,0,7]`, i.e., if `S[[i]]` is an element in `s`, then `C[[i]]` is equal to the element in `c` with the same index as `S[[i]]` in `s`, else zero.

What I have right now looks like

```
C=Array[0&,Length[S]];
j=1;
For[i=1,i<=Length[S],i++,If[MemberQ[s,S[[i]]],C[[i]]=c[[j]];j=j+1;]];
```

This works, but coming from a MATLAB background, I hate `for` loops and the above operation is a trivial indexing operation in matlab. I'm sure there is a smarter way to accomplish this, a la mathematica style. Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: This is not related to the answers below, but `C=Array[0&, ...]` is better expressed as `C = ConstantArray[0, Length[S]]`, and ten times faster to boot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is faster than what has been posted so far:

```
ss = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};   s = {1, 3, 4, 6};   c = {7, 8, 9, 7};

Replace[ss, Dispatch@Append[Thread[s -> c], _ -> 0], 1]
```

Comment: +1 for Replace and its last argument. Not sure whether Dispatch makes sense. Depends on the length of the list.

Comment: @Sjoerd A quick test indicates it has little penalty on short lists, and is drastically faster with long lists.  Why not include it?

Comment: @Wizard, that was fast. Could you explain what that last argument `1` does? I looked up in the documentation and it said it was `levelspec`, but there were no further examples to illustrate. Playing around with it, any non-zero value for it seemed to give the same answer.

Comment: @d'o-o'b Sure, but you will need to read about Levelspec in Mathematica because it is used all over.  `Replace` by default will match the entire expression (level 0) and then the pattern `_ -> 0` will match, and the output will merely be `0`.  The same problem would happen with `/.` which is `ReplaceAll`, or replace at all levels.  In this case I only want to match and replace the elements of the list `ss`, which is "level 1".  Elements of those elements would be "level 2", for example.

Comment: @d'o-o'b please read:  http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/LevelsInExpressions.html

Comment: Just to further clarify the third argument in `Replace[ ]`:  `Replace[{1,1},_->2]` returns `2`, while `Replace[{1,1},_->2,1]` returns `{2,2}`. That is because in the first case the whole list matches, while in the second the matches are over the list elements.

Answer (score 5):

You are replacing elements of S with either an element in c or with 0, so:

```
ss = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
s = {1, 3, 4, 6}
c = {7, 8, 9, 7}
r = Append[MapThread[Rule, {s, c}], Rule[_, 0]]
answer = Map[Replace[#, r] &, ss]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way.  There are probably many others.

```
s = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
subS = {1, 3, 4, 6};
c = {7, 8, 9, 7};
d= s /. {x_Integer :> If[MemberQ[subS, x], c[[Position[subS, x][[1, 1]]]], 0]}
```

I used lower case variable names throughout as is customary for user-defined symbols.

Mathematica uses curly braces are used for vectors, lists, matrices, and tables.

Comment: @d'o-o'b  I made a minor modification to the original proposal: I eliminated `Cases` after realizing that it was in fact acting on every single element in s.

Answer (score 1):

```
ss = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
s = {1, 3, 4, 6};
c = {7, 8, 9, 7};
ss /. Join[MapThread[Rule, {s, c}],Thread[Rule[Complement[ss, s], 0]]]
```

**EDIT**  or:

```
answer = 0 ss; answer[[Position[ss, #, 1] & /@ s // Flatten]] = c;
```

Answer (score 1):

If `S` is always of the form `{1, 2, ...,  n}`, (e.g., `Range[n]`) then this solution using [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SparseArray.html) is about twice as fast as @Mr. Wizard's answer in my testing for very large lists:

```
Normal[SparseArray[Thread[s -> c], n, 0]]
```

Comment: What is `Position` necessary for?

Comment: Ah, I see. `Position` is relatively slow compared to some of the alternatives in the answers to this question, and so in the scenario you describe I would expect the `Replace`/`Dispatch` technique of @Mr.Wizard to be faster.

Comment: I do not think this is a reasonable assumption based on the original question.  And if it is, isn't `Normal@SparseArray[s -> c, n]` sufficient?